# Why TextView variable needs to be inside a loop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

LinearLayout x=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.english_no);
Why this code is wrong-

```
 TextView wordview=new TextView(this);
    for(int i=0;i<english.size();i++)
    {

        wordview.setText(english.get(i));
        x.addView(wordview);
    }
```

and this one is correct-

```
for(int i=0;i<english.size();i++)
    {
        TextView wordview=new TextView(this);
        wordview.setText(english.get(i));
        x.addView(wordview);
    }
```

I couldn't understand the difference.

Comment: It is because you're just replacing the existing textview object's text in the first example whereas creating multiple textview objects in second, simultaneously assigning them the values and adding those as individual views to the layout

Comment: Thank You Man. You are amazing. it was such a simple thing XD

Answer (score 0):

here in the first example you are just referring to the first TextView that you created and changing its value and adding it to the view, eventually the `x (hoping a Linearlayout)` will have english.size() number of views where the content of every view would be same and that is the last content of `english`

Comment: Thanks Man. I got it now XD